# Cant send more than 1 piece of data from udp server to client C#

Tags: c#, sockets

so i want a udp server that sits on a computer away from me then when i want to interact with it, i connect using my computer (client). it seems its normally the client that sends data and not vise versa but in my case it needs to be the server as the server wont know my ip address to make an end point.

So far i made a udp server and client
server:

```
public class Program
{
    public static UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(11000);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected, reveiving data...");

            var data = udpServer.Receive(ref remoteEP);
            Console.WriteLine("Reveived data from " + remoteEP.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Sending data...");
            udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP);
      //    udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP); //Client still only receives once
      //    udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP);
      //    udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP);
      //    udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP);
      //    udpServer.Send(new byte[] { 1 }, 1, remoteEP);
        }
    }       
}
```

client:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public static UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();

    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStartUDP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IPEndPoint remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000);
        udpClient.Connect(remoteEp);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected, sending data...");
        udpClient.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5);
        udpClient.Send(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5);

        var receivedData = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEp);
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving data from " + remoteEp.ToString());
    }
}
```

So it seems the server just goes to the default position of listening until it receives data. then it will send 1 peice. i tried putting the send bit in a infinite loop but that only sent once aswell

here is the console logs for each if that helps

server:

Connected, reveiving data...
Reveived data from 127.0.0.1:51811
Sending data...
Connected, reveiving data...
Reveived data from 127.0.0.1:51811
Sending data...
Connected, reveiving data...

client:

Connected, sending data...
Receiving data from 127.0.0.1:11000

Comment: It will only send one piece of data per piece of data sent to it, as the Receive call is blocking your while loop until data is received

Comment: is there anyway to get around this? i cant switch the server and client and it needs to send me alot of data

Comment: You could put send and receive in separate threads.

Comment: Try putting the client Receive in a loop, it's probably sending the data multiple times but you're currently only listening for it once, from what I can see

Comment: Send & Receive in separate threads is definitely a good idea, too

Comment: i put the client receive in a while loop and its receiving all the data so ill play about with that and see if i can work that, would you be able to provide an example of how you would put send and receive on different threads as im really bad with managing threads

Comment: I cannot, but basically make two methods which contain your loops, and use Thread.Start to fire them off, or something like that